# Prevent deleting items on backspace click (PrimeVue Autocomplete multiple)

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, primevue

As per PrimeVue documentation: https://primevue.org/autocomplete/#api.autocomplete.emits.change pressing backspace in autocomplete (multiple) input field 'deletes the previous chip if the input field is empty.' Is there a way to prevent this?

I've tried adding `@input="onKeyDown"` even handler to the component and creating a method

```css
onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') {
        // This detects backspace being pressed but I need a way to stop the default behaviour.
        // event.preventDefault() isn't working in this case
        // I realise I may have to add extra checks to not disable backspace entirely but I can     worry about that later once I know how to block it in general
        }
 }
```

Thanks!